# Moq returning zero results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I`m trying to use Moq to test EntityFramework code, and somehow it returns zero results after setup.

I tried to make a parameter-less constructor on workersController - same zero items returned

```
public class WorkerDbTest
{
    private readonly Mock<IWorkerReprisatory> _repo;
    private readonly WorkersController _controller;
    private readonly List<Worker> workers;
    public WorkerDbTest()
    {
        _logger = new Mock<ILogger<WorkersController>>();
        workers = new List<Worker>
        {
            new Worker() {
                Id = 0,
                FirstName = "John",
                MiddleName = "Abraham",
                LastName = "Doe",
                Workplace = "Bomj",
                BirthDate = new DateTime(1700,10,10),
                Employed = new DateTime(1800,10,10)},
            new Worker() {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = "Alaster",
                MiddleName = "Crowly",
                LastName = "Johns",
                Workplace = "VipBomj",
                BirthDate = new DateTime(1800,12,12),
                Employed = new DateTime(1900,12,12)},
            new Worker() {
                Id = 2,
                FirstName = "Jane",
                MiddleName = "Susan",
                LastName = "Black",
                Workplace = "FemenistBobj",
                BirthDate = new DateTime(2000,11,11),
                Employed = new DateTime(2010,11,11)}
        };
        IQueryable<Worker> workersq = workers.AsQueryable();
        _repo = new Mock<IWorkerReprisatory>();
        _repo.Setup(x => x.GetAll(new WorkerQueryParameters())).Returns(workersq);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetOkResult()
    {
        var tst = _repo.Object.GetAll(new WorkerQueryParameters());
    }
}

//Controller class GetAllWorkers
public IActionResult GetAllWorkers(WorkerQueryParameters workerQueryParameters)
    {
        //_logger.LogInformation("GetAllCustomersStarted");
        var allWorkers = _workerRepository.GetAll(workerQueryParameters).ToList();
        var allWorkersDTO = allWorkers.Select(x => Mapper.Map<WorkerDTO>(x));
        if(Response != null)
        {
            Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination",
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { totalCount = _workerRepository.Count() }));
        }
        return Ok(allWorkersDTO);
    }
```

At the current time allWorkers object results 0 entries after being called.
So I wanted to test out if I have any result from Mock object which then got var tst and there are still no entries.

Suppose that GetAll() Should return me those three guys I added there as iQueryables

Comment: try  var tst = _repo.GetAll(new WorkerQueryParameters()); without Object

Comment: Without .Object it drops en exception in VS2017:
Mock<IWorkerReprisatory> Does not contain method GetAl()

Comment: Try something like: Setup(x => x.GetAll(It.IsAny<WorkerQueryParameters>)).Returns(workersq);

Comment: Sorry, one more advise do Moq and call with same variable _params=  new WorkerQueryParameters();_repo.Setup(x => x.GetAll(_params)).Returns(workersq);

Comment: @Silvermurk How does the controller and logger come into play in this test? Also you seem to be testing the mock and not anything concrete. I also see nothing indicating that the code in mention relates to entity framework

Comment: Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: Details appear to be missing from your [mcve]

Comment: You are mocking `IWorkerReprisatory` but that's the very thing you are actually testing. That's not how it works. You need to post the code you want to test so we can see it. Otherwise we cannot help you test something we cannot see.

Comment: @CodingYoshi
Edited the original post, please look at chcnges about Controller.GetAllWorkers()

Comment: You have to mock `_workerRepository.GetAll` and  stub `WorkerQueryParameters` then test `GetAllWorkers` to see if the correct result is returned. You also have to reproduce the case when `Response` is not null so you can test that code in the if block too.

Comment: @CodingYoshi
Wonders happen, and somewhy Nikosi`s idea did the trick. 
_params= new WorkerQueryParameters();_repo.Setup(x => x.GetAll(_params)).Returns(workersq);

Comment: It's not a wonder. That is saying that whenever `GetAll` is called on the `IWorkerReprisatory`, return `workersq`. Which is fine when you are testing the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup method is matching on the an actual object refrence of `WorkerQueryParameters`, you'll need to use the same object refrence or, you'll need to match a given value with `It.Is<WorkerQueryParameters>(x => x.Value == true)` or just match any `It.Any<WorkerQueryParameters>()`, for example:

```
    _repo.Setup(x => x.GetAll(It.Any<WorkerQueryParameters>())).Returns(workersq);
```

It might also be worth setting your mock to be strick so that it throws instead of just returning null or default.

```
    _repo = new Mock<IWorkerReprisatory>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

Comment: Not that your answer answers the question but just wanted to point out that in this case, `It.Any<WorkerQueryParameters>()` is not a good at all because this very thing dictates what the method returns. Thus you want to be very specific and ensure it is not just any but the very specific object.

Comment: @CodingYoshi totally agree I was just giving options. for this example, I'd go with matching the actual reference.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhy adding a param at startup and using it instead of New WorkerQueryParams() did the trick. I still have no idea why, but it works perfectly fine, and returns 3 entries. 
Thanks to everyone envolved and @Nikosi for his idea)

```
_params= new WorkerQueryParameters()
_repo.Setup(x => x.GetAll(_params)).Returns(workersq);
IQueryable<Worker> tst = _repo.Object.GetAll(_params);
var OkResponse = _controller.GetAllWorkers(_params);
```

Comment: In your setup in your question, you are setting up `x.GetAll(new WorkerQueryParameters()`. In other words you're telling the Moq framework that whenever GetAll with that object is called to return whatever you're returning. Then in the `Fact` you are calling it with a whole other `WorkerQueryParameters`, so Moq does not return anything because these are different different objects. But in this answer it works because you are setting up and calling with the same object.

Comment: Read @kevinsmith answer because it is helpful and explains this (I would even upvote his answer if I were you because he suggested how to fix your issue). Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @CodingYoshi
Will do, and thanks really lot for your time to explain all this to me:)